# How can I add developer options to another user in Android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My question is simple: How can I add developer options to another user in Android 4.2.2?

I read this thread ([Android 4.2 developer settings still unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable)), but anyone said how to resolve it.

Thanks for the answers.