# Android 6.0, Nexus 5. Second user (not owner) not see "Developer options"

Tags: android

Android 6.0, Nexus 5. I have two users:

- Alex (owner)
- Peter

When I login as *Alex* I want to see *Developer options*. So, I go to *Settings >> About phone*  and tap 7 times on *Build Number*. As result, I get *Developer options*.

When I login as *Peter*, I do not see the *Developer options*. I tap 7 times on *Build Number*, but I don't see the same as with the other account.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only the main user (owner) has access to Developer Options.**

Related questions: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/53837/developer-options-for-a-second-user-on-android-4-3 and [Android 4.2 developer settings still unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223748/android-4-2-developer-settings-still-unavailable)